# Laravel Datatables while using Entrust Package

Tags: php, laravel, package

I'm using entrust package for roles management , i have impleted that in my project based on the steps which mentioned in github , it's working fine but for assigning roles to user page we are getting values from two queries which i mentioned below , if the user list goes upto 100 how can i get user details easily , i want datatables for this view can anyone please help me to view as datatables format and i already configured yajra datatables for my project , it is working for other pages, we are using  https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust

Controller.php

```
  public function index()
{
    $company_id=Auth::user()->company_id;
    $users=User::where('company_id',$company_id)->get();
    $allRoles=Role::where('company_id',$company_id)->get();
    return view('usersroles.index',compact(['users','allRoles']));
}
```

view.blade.php

```
<table class="table table-bordered" >
    <tr class="thead-cls">
        <th class="center">Name</th>
        <th class="center">Employee Id</th>
        <th class="center">Roles</th>
        <th class="center">Action</th>
    </tr>
    @forelse($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td class="center">{{$user->name}}</td>
            <td class="center">{{$user->emp_id}}</td>
            <td class="center">
                @foreach( $user->roles as $role)
                    {{$role->name}},
                @endforeach

            </td>

            <td class="center">
            @permission('users-roles-edit') 
                <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-add" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-{{$user->id}}">
                    Edit
                </button>
             @endrole
                <!-- Modal -->
                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal-{{$user->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                                            aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"> Editing<b> {{$user->name}}'s</b> Role</h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <form action="{{route('usersroles.update',$user->id)}}" method="post" role="form" id="role-form-{{$user->id}}">
                                    {{csrf_field()}}
                                    {{method_field('PATCH')}}
                                    <div class="form-group">

                                        <select name="roles[]" multiple required="">
                                            @foreach($allRoles as $role)
                                                <option value="{{$role->id}}">{{$role->name}}</option>
                                            @endforeach
                                        </select>

                                    </div>

                                    {{--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>--}}
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-add" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-add" onclick="$('#role-form-{{$user->id}}').submit()">Save changes</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @empty
        <td>No users</td>
    @endforelse
</table>   

   [![Need Datatables for this view][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this piece of code in your view with `jQuery`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
```

`#myTable` is the id of your table. For more info, [read the documentation](https://datatables.net/).

Comment: it is possible to add this without using datatables

Comment: Yes. But you're referring to `dataTables`. What's your exact problem?